# Car shakes upon startup, dies. Other times gas pedal does not respond

Tags: ford, sparkplugs, emissions, ranger, fuel-pump

I'm pretty uneducated when it comes cars but im hoping you guys can help me. I have a 99 Ford Ranger that upon startup (not every time) shakes extremely hard and then dies. Other times when driving I feel the gas pedal shift and it's like the accelerator doesn't work. But then after decelerating for a few seconds it kicks back on and works again. I changed my MAF but im not sure what else could be the culprit. Checked fuel pressure and it's good. What good be the culprit? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you had the codes read? If so, what are the exact codes? If not, can you get them read?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2♦ yes no codes are showing. no check engine light. There was a check engine light when my MAF was bad but I replaced it and the light went away. Yet the problem still persists.

Comment: Is the problem intermittent then? Will it run perfectly fine at other times?

Comment: sounds like a vacuum leak...check the pvc hose toward the back

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2♦ Only intermittently. The car will shake heavily and turn off typically when I have driven it a bit that day and it is hot outside. But at least once throughout every trip (15 mins) my accelerator stops working for a few seconds. If not multiple times throughout the trip.

Comment: Is the truck drive by wire or cable? I don't remember, but would assume it's drive by cable. When the accelerator stops working, does the engine just sort of "die" or does it keep running but it doesn't speed up or slow down when you press it?

Comment: What do you mean by “the gas pedal shifts”?

Comment: @Ben sorry for my probably inappropriate use of automotive jargon, but it feels as if the car almost enters a lower gear, after this the accelerator in ineffective and i begin decelerating. After about 3 seconds of decelerating the gas pedal begins working again. This happens a couple times throughout the trip.

Comment: This happens with constant pedal application? Does the pedal tend to stick? Any correlation do driving conditions? If you have an obd2 scantool try watching the Throttle position sensor voltage next time it happens. If possible datalog the event and do a TPS sweep key on engine off.

Comment: @Ben Yes with constant pedal application, then when I feel it "shift" I begin decelerating and my foot on the pedal is ineffective. This tends to happen when its hot outside but where I live its always hot. Also my spark plugs don't look great but i'm not really sure if that could be the culprit.

Comment: @Ben @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2♦ Went out for a test drive just now and when i went to take a turn I put my foot down to accelerate through the turn and it didn't accelerate at all, I kept my foot downand suddenly it decided to accelerate at full normal speed. Though this was strange and might help with diagnosis.